# Change window cursor with pure CSS

Tags: css, mouse-cursor

I know you can change the cursor of a web page with an image, but is it possible to 'style' the cursor only using CSS?

Something like...

```
div.changecursor:cursor {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: blue;
    border-radius: 199px; /* make it a circle */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cursor property allows the use of an url linking an image to be used as cursor.
In that way you may customize as much as you want

property and value

```
.classX {
cursor: url(myCursor.cur);
}
```

Ok with a gif, etc

Comment: Yeah I knew I could change the 'image', but I'm looking to style it with pure CSS, such as setting the width and background color. Is this possible? If so could you show an example?

Comment: Sorry I didnt notice you mentioned  to know about the url. As far as I know , using css besides the url we have the predifined styles available ( crosshair, help, move, etc...) but not the possibility of styling as an element.